# How to remove special characters from a class object C#

Tags: c#, class, reflection, properties, attributes

I have a class object with nearly 200 properties and need to remove the special characters from the property value. What is the efficient way to remove the special characters from the properties in a class object. The properties in a class contains special characters while receiving input from service. If the properties are less in a class then it can be done for each property. Is there a way to remove special characters from the properties other than using reflection ?

Comment: Do you actually mean 'special' characters in the properties' values or C# reserved characters in the properties' names?

Comment: Property (getters and setters) values. For an example property FirstName must contain only alphabets but by mistake the service (user sends - it's typo and user side no validation) special characters too. The special characters are available in many places. So need to remove the special characters for all the properties in the class. If the number properties are less then regex method can be called and removed the special chracter for each property. Now the class has more than 200 properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With 200 properties (and maybe more in the future) the best option is probably to use reflection as you suggested and combine with a regex.

```
public void CleanupPropertyValues()
{
    PropertyInfo[] properties = 
        typeof(Person).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);

    foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
    {
        if (property.PropertyType == typeof(string))
        {
            string currentValue = (string)property.GetValue(this, null);

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(currentValue))
            {
                string newValue = _cleanupRegex.Replace(currentValue, "");

                if (newValue != currentValue)
                {
                    property.SetValue(this, newValue);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
private static Regex _cleanupRegex = new Regex("[^A-Za-z]");
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/nccu3q)

Answer (score 0):

A first approach would be to parametrized the attributes of the class and then passing regular expression to each one.

With the library using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

Then do a regular expression you cant test before here: https://regexr.com

And then create an object of the class Regex. After that pass your regex expression to the strings.

You can see an example in Microsoft Doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex?view=netcore-3.1